# Finding the Ring of Truth

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, rebus

[image: First 3 of 7 rebuses]

[image: Last 4 of 7 rebuses]

Tips:

1. First, wait on others.
2. Remember: overlap is chaff.

The answer is a 7-letter word.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The word you looking for is

> **[VERITAS](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/veritas#:%7E:text=(%CB%88v%C9%9Br%C9%AA%CB%8Ct%C3%A6s%20),Collins%20English%20Dictionary.)** (meaning truth)

The rebuses in order:

> 1)
>  Alien-ale=in
>  Targets-tart=ges
>  Tread-red=ta
>  **INGESTA**
>
>  2)
>  Blues-us=ble
>  Sticks-tick=ss
>  Heart-hat=er
>  **BLESSER**
>
>  3)
>  Casket-Cake=st
>  Pair-pi=ar
>  Dodecagon-decagon=do
>  Comb-cob=m
>  **STARDOM**
>
>  4)
>  Cleaver-lever=Ca
>  Holster-hose=ltr
>  Table tops-tablets=op
>  **CALTROP**
>
>  5)
>  Dog ear-gear=Do
>  Plums-plus=m
>  Lattice-latte=ic
>  Starling-string=al
>  **DOMICAL**
>
>  6)
>  Coaster-coat=Ser
>  Carving-car=ving
>  **SERVING**
>
>  7)
>  Rowing-wing=Ro
>  Plaid-lid=pa
>  Blade-ad=ble
>  **ROPABLE**

The title refers to:

> Making a chain by over lapping the suffixes of a word over the matching prefix of another word like so (where the end letters in italics overlap too):

> ***SER***V**ING**E**STA**R**DOM**I**CAL**T**ROP**A**BLE**S***SER***

> [image]

> By then taking away overlapping letters of the chain one gets **VERITAS** in a loop.

> [image]

> Hence we have found our ‘**RING OF TRUTH**’

Comment: I think the title refers to something in the puzzle!

Comment: Sorry, this is incorrect

Comment: Just messing with you, PDT! You nailed it! Good job.